# time_start scope time_end helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

hi im new in ruby on rails 
here is my scenario i have two timers `time_star` and `time_end` 
im just wondering if there is a validator or helper that will change the time of the `end time` based on the time of the start time in order not to get a negative value upon getting the difference of the two time it is yes possible in jquery but i want to know if rails can also do this

example if i choose 1pm on `time_start` then `time_end` will only show 2pm onwards

im also researching it now im just hopping there may be many possible answer here

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different approaches to achieve different goals.

1. You can write custom validator to prevent `time_end` that lower than `time_start` to be stored to the database. Or you can pay attention on standart `numericality` validator, maybe it will be enough for you.
2. You can write some helpers, JS or other view related code to allow user choose `time_end` value only greater than `time_start` in the html widget.
   In my opinion, it's quite a specific task and unlikely you will find something in rails for it, but it can be realized in a few lines of code according to your wishes.